# When are (semi)off-topic statements in an answer acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm asking this question because of answers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958889/1010175

Normally I would say that it's always best to stick to the specific question asked, but I can see some scenarios where it might be appropriate for someone to stray from the actual question asked.

For example, if someone asks the question, "I'm migrating my company's website from AES-128 to the more secure Triple-DES for storing passwords, here's my code, please help", I would hope that people would point out all the things wrong with that question! (3Des is insecure, store passwords as hashes not reversible encryption, etc).

But the question I linked to is a simple one: explain the difference between the encryption modes (CBC ECB CTR OCB CFB), and the accepted answer by myforwik seems to answer that pretty well.

Perseids' answer, however, seems a bit off topic.  He spends the first half ranting (side note: the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22958889/revisions) of his answer didn't have the second part which actually answered the question).

**Is this appropriate?** It's not exactly spam or offensive, and doesn't exactly fall into the "non-answer" category, so I don't feel comfortable flagging it.  In fact, his warning is completely legitimate.  But it's still seems more like a rant than an answer.

Also, if it's *not* appropriate, what should be done about it?  I don't feel comfortable editing someone else's answer, and flagging doesn't seem right for this case.  Down-voting is obviously an answer, but I'm curious what others think about this.

Comment: This type of answer is common for [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the answer saves one person from doing something foolish in their code, who cares if it's not answering the question exactly as asked?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: that makes sense, but I'm not convinced the linked question is really an XY problem; it just seems like the answerer is (erroneously?) assuming it is.

Comment: Remember, Stack Overflow is not just there to help the person who asked the original question; it's also there to help the thousands of people who visit from google searching for answers to similar questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this appropriate? It's not exactly spam or offensive, and doesn't exactly fall into the "non-answer" category, so I don't feel comfortable flagging it [...] and flagging doesn't seem right for this case...

Why the focus on flagging? It would be inappropriate to flag this answer.

> I don't feel comfortable editing someone else's answer

You shouldn't edit it unless you notice an error in it, or some phrasing needs correcting.

> Down-voting is obviously an answer, but I'm curious what others think about this.

It's definitely an answer and clearly a number of people have found the answer helpful. Up or down voting it is solely at your discretion. If you're confused and unsure then walk away and do nothing. We ask you to judge content based on your experience and technical knowledge, if it simply makes you *"feel funny but you're not sure why"* then don't do anything to it - let the rest of the community make a decision.